# Почему не печатается часть данных

Tags: json, golang

Есть код в котором из БД берется поле data с архивными и не архивным json строками(1я строка архив, 2я и до 5й json текст, 6я архив. С помощью zlib разархивируется и выводится 1я, 6я строка, а вот json строки пропускает. Надо чтоб выводилось все вместе на экран. Знаю что надо повторно вызвать json.Unmarshal, но все равно не получается. Если кто может, подскажите.Спасибо.

```
package main

import (
"database/sql"
"log"
_"github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
"compress/zlib"
"bytes"
"encoding/json"
"fmt"
"io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "name:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:port)/database")
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
defer db.Close()

rows, err := db.Query(`SELECT data FROM user_stats ORDER BY created_at LIMIT 6`)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer rows.Close()

for rows.Next() {
    var data []byte
    err := rows.Scan(&data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    type UserStatsData struct {
        Revenue float64 `json:"r"`
        Gold int `json:"g"`
    }

    userStatsData := UserStatsData{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &userStatsData); err != nil {
        r, err := zlib.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(data))
        if err != nil {
            log.Panicf("\nCannot read archive %v", err);
        }
        r.Close()
        output, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r)
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", output)
 }
```

}

Comment: Задача не понятна. `Date sql.Rows "json:\"d\""` - вот это что должно делать по-вашему? json не кодится и не декодится напрямую в/из `sql.Rows`.

Comment: Эта строка не нужна, удалил. А в целом понятно что мне нужно?

Comment: Честно говоря, не очень. Покажите образец того, как выглядит data и что вы в итоге хотите.

Comment: Есть БД в которой поле data имеет много строк как архивных так и текстовых(json формат) мне надо декомпресс данных сделать и вывести это все на экран, декомпресс получается сделать, но вот текстовые данные не выводятся вместе с разархивированными.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в куске

```
if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &userStatsData); err != nil {
    r, err := zlib.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(data))
```

у вас дальнейшая обработка происходит только если при чтении json произошло ошибка, т.е. если данные заархивированы.

Я думаю вам нужно что-то примерно следующее:

```
userStatsData := UserStatsData{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &userStatsData); err != nil {
    r, err := zlib.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(data))
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicf("\nCannot read archive %v", err);
    }
    r.Close()
    data, _ = ioutil.ReadAll(r)
}
fmt.Printf("%s\n", data)
```

я тут:

1. Вынес вывод данных за пределы условия о проверке json-валидности
2. При распаковывании архива подменяю данные из базы на распакованные данные

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное, все оказалось намного проще!

Comment: Рад, что помог. Если это то что вам нужно - поставьте галочку об ответе, и мне будет приятно и другие посетители будут видеть что вопрос решён.